# Android - Firebase - Viewholder, custom method called After onChildRemoved - So no changes

Tags: android, database, firebase

So I have a **recyclerView with a viewHolder** that allows the user to **like/unlike an item**. When clicking outside of that icon, we show a page detail; which works fine. (see pic below)

**Problem:** I have a "liked" activity that lists the liked items and when unliking one of them, the corresponding item should disappear when the onChildRemoved is triggered. Unfortunately I realize that the onChildRemoved is triggered just before the unliking method.

**Edit - clarification:** The unliking method removes the item from the Firebase database; but there is no "refresh" on the UI and the item remains there.

**Question:** How could I trigger the unliking method before the onChildRemoved? Or should I implement another listener, but how?

Below the sequence displayed in Logs:

```
07-01 16:21:30.761 17802-17802/com.yatoo V/com.item: in on Child Added
07-01 16:21:30.761 17802-17802/com.yatoo V/com.item: Get Updates Called
07-01 16:21:36.731 17802-17802/com.yatoo V/com.item: in on Child Removed
07-01 16:21:36.731 17802-17802/com.yatoo V/com.item: Get Updates Called
07-01 16:21:36.911 17802-17802/com.yatoo V/com.item: Viewholder in on complete Unlike - Item Removed
```

**The like/unlike methods are in the viewholder**

```
    @Override
        public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {

            mFirebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference queryRef = mFirebaseRef.child("users").child(UserUID).child("favorites").child(item.getUniqueID());

            queryRef.setValue(item, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError firebaseError, DatabaseReference firebase) {
                    if (firebaseError != null) {
                        Utils.showSnack(itemView, R.string.error_data_not_saved +" "+firebaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {

            mFirebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference queryRef = mFirebaseRef.child("users").child(UserUID).child("favorites").child((item.getUniqueID()));

            queryRef.setValue(null, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Viewholder: in on complte Unlike");
                    Utils.showSnack(itemView, context.getString(R.string.item_favorite_removed));
                }
            });

            queryRef.removeValue();
        }
```

**Here is the recyclerView code with the "getUpdates" method below**

```
RecyclerView favoritesRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.favorites_recyclerview);
            GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,  2);
            favoritesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

            userUID = SharedPreferenceManager.getUserUid(this);

            mUserFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userUID).child("favorites");

            ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, "in on Child Added");
                    getUpdates(dataSnapshot);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, "in on Child Changed");
                    getUpdates(dataSnapshot);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, "in on Child Removed");
                    getUpdates(dataSnapshot);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, "in on Child Moved");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            };

            mUserFirebase.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
            itemList = new ArrayList<>();
            itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this);
            itemAdapter.setListener(this);
            favoritesRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        }
```

**Corresponding getUpdates method within the Activity**

```
 public void getUpdates(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

    itemList.clear();

    if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
        Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Get Updates Called");
        Item item = dataSnapshot.getValue(Item.class);
        itemList.add(item);
        itemAdapter.refreshItem(itemList);
    }
 }
```

[image: Item and like/unlike icon]

Comment: remove `queryRef.removeValue();` you are already setting things to null before that line

Comment: Should I elaborate my question further? Do you miss any additional information to make it more accurate? Thanks

Comment: The library used is the following: https://github.com/jd-alexander/LikeButton

Comment: try joining [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a solution.
I implemented a listener in the adapter and everything went smoothly.